# How to check a CIDR range in Athena?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, presto, trino

I have to get results in Athena if a dstaddr is inside a certain CIDR range. This is my current command:

This is my current command:

```
SELECT * FROM "default"."test3" WHERE dstaddr LIKE '3.250.243.%';
```

But my CIDR range is 3.250.243.64/26 so I can't use the LIKE (/24).
I tried a bit with this [function](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/ip.html) but I didn't get it working.

How can I check if my dstaddr is inside the CIDR range 3.250.243.64/26 in Athena?

Comment: I've tried to answer, but if it does not work please provide some sample data and desired output.

Answer (score 2):

You can try Trino's [`contains`](https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/ipaddress.html):

```sql
select contains('3.250.243.64/26', IPADDRESS '3.250.243.63'),
       contains('3.250.243.64/26', IPADDRESS '3.250.243.64'),
       contains('3.250.243.64/26', IPADDRESS '3.250.243.65'),
       contains('3.250.243.64/26', IPADDRESS '3.250.243.127'),
       contains('3.250.243.64/26', IPADDRESS '3.250.243.128');
```

Output:

| _col0 | _col1 | _col2 | _col3 | _col4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| false | true | true | true | false |

Which as I understand should be synonym for Presto's:

```sql
SELECT is_subnet_of(IPPREFIX '3.250.243.64/26', IPADDRESS '3.250.243.128');
```

Hence you will need to trim the end of the `dstaddr` if it contains the mask (also you might need `cast(dstaddr as IPADDRESS)`)

Comment: Trino functions are supported as of Athena engine version 3: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/functions.html